# Dynamic table names with JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have versioned tables like

1. table_0001
2. table_0002
3. table_0003

The tables having the same structure but different data as per version.
Version will be received at runtime so could not create entity with table name as it will be dynamic. Is there any way where we can provide some strategy to use same entity and use dynamic table name.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I want to get an Idea if this is possible using JPA.

Comment: Since tha tables have same structure, consider adding a version column, so you don't need several tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible with jpa because create or update tables at project opening. I suggest Entity-Attribute-Value model for design dynamic table system.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read more about `@Audited` annotation in `Hibernate`, in reference it is declared as below:

> For each audited entity, a table will be created, which will hold the
> history of changes made to the entity. You can then retrieve and query
> historical data without much effort.

Here you can read more about it:

https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/